# How to create an average of system time in R?

Tags: r

Having issues trying to average the values of the system time (pr) taken to factorize 2 primes multiplied together.
Currently have it working with one iteration but unsure how to get it to work with n iterations.

```
require("gmp")
prime<-function(a) {
  pr <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = a)
  sz <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = a)
  for(i in 1:a){
    y<-urand.bigz(nb = 2, size = i)
    p1<-nextprime(as.bigz(y[1]))
    p2<-nextprime(as.bigz(y[2]))
    p<-p1*p2

    pr[i] <-system.time(factorize(p))[1]
    sz[i] <-sizeinbase(p)
  }
  return(cbind(sz,pr))
}
times <- prime(48)


plot(times,xlab="Size of Psuedoprime ",ylab="Time taken to factorize", main="Size of Vs Time taken to factorize of a given Pseudoprime")
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
prime<-function(a) {
  pr <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = sum(a))
  sz <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = sum(a))
  for(j in 1:length(a)){

    for(i in 1:a[j]){
      y<-urand.bigz(nb = 2, size = i)
      p1<-nextprime(as.bigz(y[1]))
      p2<-nextprime(as.bigz(y[2]))
      p<-p1*p2

      if(j == 1){
        pr[i] <-system.time(factorize(p))[1]
        sz[i] <-sizeinbase(p)
      }else{
        pr[sum(a[1:(j-1)]) + i] <- system.time(factorize(p))[1]
        sz[sum(a[1:(j-1)]) + i] <-sizeinbase(p)
      }

    }
  }

  return(cbind(sz,pr))
}
times <- prime(c(48, 52))
```